# GridView crashes on touchscreen works with mouse

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a Windows Store app (C#/XAML). I have a default GridView control inside a UserControl. Here is the entire code:

```
<GridView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" SelectedIndex="{Binding Priority, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
               <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Border Width="30" Height="30" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF1BA1E2">
                        <TextBlock Text="!" Foreground="#FF1BA1E2" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Border Width="30" Height="30" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FFFFC800">
                        <TextBlock Text="!!" Foreground="#FFFFC800" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Border Width="30" Height="30" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FFFF0000">
                        <TextBlock Text="!!!" Foreground="#FFFF0000" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </GridViewItem>
            </GridView>
```

The whole thing works very with mouse. However, when I submitted the app, I got a crash report telling me that this GridView crashes on touchscreen devices. So, I tested with the simulator and indeed the app crashes when you try to touch any GridViewItem! I haven't done anything funny here. The default GridView seems to have a bug. Can something be done?

Edit1: For the reference, here is the app: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/1cd03a7e-03c1-4625-b021-fb22b3ec999b
The concerned grid view can be seen by clicking 'edit task' button.

Edit2: I tried creating a completely new UserControl with only this GridView inside. Still got the crash! Replaced GridView with similar ListBox - same results! However, similar conditions (UserControl loaded as a child of border on some event) in new app work perfectly fine! Something related to my app? What it could be?

Comment: can't regenerate the bug, all works well in simulator in touch mode.

Comment: @Xyroid what is your suggestion? Should I try creating a blank app and see if I can recreate the issue? In case issue occurs with a blank app, would this be machine specific compiler problem? I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Yes try creating a blank app and see in different machines.

Answer (score 0):

I catch this  crash
But I can't say nothing without more details. I am not sure that problem is in the xaml. How do you add events? how do you change states?

Comment: I have no events in the whole UserControl. It's just the two way binding. And crash occurs even without the binding. Message I get (inside the simulator) says that the current attached debugger is unable to handle the exception. Possible new debuggers are new instance of VS2012.